# Unable to exctract html table from the dynamic web page using selenium web driver Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to exctract the table from the web page ,bellow is my script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requets
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time, sys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(20)

URL = 'https://www.ccee.org.br/portal/faces/pages_publico/o-que-fazemos/como_ccee_atua/precos/precos_medios?_adf.ctrl-state=7e1fw5zdn_14&_afrLoop=19197915280379#!%40%40%3F_afrLoop%3D19197915280379%26_adf.ctrl-state%3D7e1fw5zdn_18'

driver.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
time.sleep(10)
table = soup.find('table')

list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll(["td"]):
        text = cell.text
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

for item in list_of_rows:
    ' '.join(item)

Data = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)
Export_Path = os.path.join(PY_Space, 'Source_Data.csv')
KN.PrintTF('\n>> Raw Data Exported to path: '+ Export_Path)

Data.to_csv(Export_Path,index = False)
```

I am unable to get the table . Please help

Comment: what is the error you get by running this code?

Comment: i am not getting any error in the code but my output table coming as blank.

Comment: please, try to run the code, fix it if it doesn't run, update it in the question and post the output you get and expected output